# Should I cache a database table in memory?

Tags: .net, database, caching

In my windows based application I have some data that should be retrieved from the database ex: **authorized_dealers** from the **dealers** table. this data is used across multiple Data Access Layer Classes for Validation Purposes.

Currently I am getting the DATA from the database through a **DTO** object and populating a **list(of Dealers)**.

My question is that should i Put this List as a Global List in my utilities class so it is populated once and shared thus minimizing database hits,
or should it reside in a Data Access Layer Class of its own and get Called every time the list is needed and thus getting the data each time from the database.

Comment: You can enjoy both worlds without adding mutable state. You can make add a caching layer which checks first if the list of dealers already exists. If not, hit the database.

Comment: With a little care in designing your data access layer you can allow for caching (as per @YuvalItzchakov's comment) but not implement any caching until you have evidence you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you currently have a performance problem? If not, you *don't* want to bother yourself with cache invalidation, which is what you need as soon as you introduce caching.

Comment: We don't have any performance problem but the table in question is a Info Table only and will not change through the application.@CodeCaster

Comment: It doesn't matter who changes it. If it changes, ever, you need to be able to detect that from your running application and invalidate the cache (i.e. reload it from the database).

Comment: @CodeCaster Although cache invalidation definitely sucks, there are plenty of already existing solutions to dealing with it. I wouldn't be too scared of it if needed.

Comment: @Yuval keyword being "if needed". Don't add unnecessary complexity. The database itself is pretty good at caching too.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree, no need to run to caching layers only because "im hitting the database".

Comment: @CodeCaster is there any other downside for caching the table other than dealing with Invalid Caching. I mean is this the only purpose i shouldn't load the table in the memory. Sorry if  I am Being too General

Comment: @nayef the term is "cache invalidation", not "invalid caching". The other reason why you shouldn't add it, I explained in my previous comment: don't add unnecessary complexity to your application just because you can.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry for the mistake in Terminology and thanks for your Help.